# VBS script that runs on file selected in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, vbscript, explorer

Is there a way to have a VBS script process a manually selected file in Windows Explorer?

I know about adding commands that are run by right-clicking in a Windows Explorer window (regedit HKEY CLASSES ROOT * Shell etc.): this means I can run a VBscript without actually dclicking it, which should make it possible to have the VB script process a manually selected file other than the script itself. My problem is I do not know how to tell the VBscript to process the file I manually select in windows explorer. In other words: I would like to be able to select a file in the file explorer, right click to launch the VB script - whatever the script does - and have that VB script process the file I just selected. I searched the web extensively but haven't found any coverage of this feature.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a "how to" that adds a "Take Ownership" context menu to Windows Explorer. Its a different use case but perhaps you can adapt the `IsolatedCommand` entry in the `Add Take Ownership to Context menu.reg` file so it runs your vbscript command. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: Thank you, I tried the How To you suggested and that works with batch/shell commands! Only the batch uses %1% variables as arguments to the cmd line in the registry. I wonder if you can use VBS Arguments the same way...

Comment: Actually, I forgot to specify that %1% is what the batch command in the registry entry actually uses to get the name of the file that is manually selected (i.e. highlighted using the mouse) in the file explorer and on which the batch operates.